# Abnormal bar on histogramm (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I have some grouped data and do:

```
df.hist(by=df['weekday'])
```

but I see some Abnormal blue bars on all histogramms:

[image: hist]

If I write

```
df[df['weekday'] == 0]
```

It doesn't return any 0 datas:

[image: data example]

How remove this blue artefacts and what is it?

Comment: Can you show what your desired chart should look like?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a2ky.png without blue artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, 'weekday' in you DataFrame is an intager.

You have 2 ways:

1. convert 'weekday' from INT to STR
2. use 'column' atribute:

   df.hist(column = 'count', by=df['weekday'])